# Extra Argument In Call?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I've been trying to resolve this "EXTRA ARGUMENT 'title' IN CALL" ALL week. Below is the code with the error I'm having trouble with. I've added the new code that I'm currently working with in Xcode. The error I'm getting with this code is:

> "ARGUMENT PASSED TO CALL THAT TAKES NO ARGUMENTS"

**NEW CODE**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct PostStruct {
    struct PostStruct {
        let title: String
        let message : String
    }
}

class DatabaseViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts: [PostStruct] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let title = snapshotValue?["title"] as? String

            let message = snapshotValue?["message"] as? String

            self.posts.insert(PostStruct(title: title ?? "", message: message ?? ""), at: 0) **// <-- ARGUMENT PASSED TO CALL THAT TAKES NO ARGUMENTS**
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        post()
    }

    func post(){
        let title = "Title"
        let message = "Message"

        let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title" : title as AnyObject, "message" : message as AnyObject]

         let databaseRef  = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "New value"
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "New value"
            return cell!
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "" //reset value
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "" // resetValue
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "New value"
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "New value"
            return cell!
        }
    }
}
```

**OLD CODE**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct PostStruct {
    let title = String!.self
    let message : String!
}

class DatabaseViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts = [postStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let title = snapshotValue?["title"] as? String

            let message = snapshotValue?["message"] as? String

            self.posts.insert(PostStruct(title: title ,message: message), at: 0) // **<--  EXTRA ARGUMENT 'title' IN CALL**
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        post()
    }

    func post(){
```

Comment: If `postStruct` is actually a Struct like its name implies, you should capitalize it as `PostStruct`; that's a Swift convention, so following it makes things clearer for everyone. Does `PostStruct` have an `init` that takes both a `title` and a `message`?

Comment: Post struct is just the name of the struct & no it doesn't have an init. @Connor

Comment: Use autocompletion feature to insert the postStruct into the array. also if it doesn't work, try postStruct.init and that should autocomplete the arguments and satisfy the compiler and yourself.

Comment: there's no autocompletion suggestions also, I tried to input 'postStruct.init' and I got the error "Can not call value of non-function type 'postStruct' @DominikBucher

Comment: @LaniMJ then take the object initialization out of the insert function and try again.

Comment: You need to show enough code to explain what your `postStruct` is. Add the definition of `postStruct`.

Comment: how do I do that? @OOPer

Comment: Sorry, I was too short. You have your code including the definition of `postStruct`. Please show it to us by adding the definition to your question.

Comment: No worries! It's added! @OOPer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two critical flaws:

The definition of `PostStruct` should be something like this:

```
struct PostStruct {
    let title: String
    let message : String
}
```

The line `let title = String!.self` declares your `title` as having a class object, not `String`.

And another is the line `DatabaseViewController`:

```
var posts = [post]
```

In your code, `post` is a method, I believe you do not want an Array of methods.

Which should be something like this:

```
var posts: [PostStruct] = []
```

And to make two fixes above to work, you need a little more:

```
        self.posts.insert(PostStruct(title: title ?? "", message: message ?? ""), at: 0)
```

You may have some other faults in your code, but at least you need the fixes above. Try them.

Comment: I added the replacement  "self.posts.insert(PostStruct(title: title ?? "", message: message ?? ""), at: 0)" but now I'm getting the error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: Have you replaced the definition of `PostStruct` as shown?

Comment: I really do appreciate the help, I'm new at Xcode and I know I probably sound like a babbling idiot! @OOPer

Comment: and yes!  @OOPer

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error _Argument passed to call that takes no arguments_ in my Xcode. If Clean Build does not work, please add your latest code into your question (this time you should not remove the old code, as it is explaining the problem shown in the title.)

Comment: I updated the thread with the latest code. I also tried command+B to clean build but that didn't work, still got the same error.

Comment: @LaniMJ, I see. You have a slight mistake when updating your definition of `PostStruct`. It should be `struct PostStruct { let title: String let message: String}` not `struct PostStruct { struct PostStruct { let title: String let message : String } }`. Remove outer `struct PostStruct {` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PostStruct` struct has a default value for the `title` property. The automatically-generated initializer will only contain parameters for values that don't already have a default, which is why the automatic initializer has `message` as a parameter and not `title`. Also, your default value for `title` is the `String` type itself, rather than an instance of a string, which I doubt is what you want. I also doubt that the properties of `PostStruct` really need to be implicitly-unwrapped optionals.

Declare the struct like this, and your initializer should work:

```
struct PostStruct {
    let title: String
    let message: String
}
```